# Docker problems in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker

After updating to ubuntu 20.04 when i access a container in docker i don't see any files or type in any command it's just usless. So is there something to do with the docker in the new ubuntu version or?

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

This answer was posted when no official support and documentation were available for ubuntu 20.04.

Now you should follow the official guide at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

**[Old answer] Go through these commands one by one.**

1. Uninstall old versions. Older versions of Docker were called docker, docker.io, or docker-engine. If these are installed, uninstall them by using:

   `sudo apt remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc docker-compose`
2. Install docker engine

   `sudo apt install docker-compose`
3. Add your user to docker group to be able to run commands without sudo

   `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
4. Log out and log back in for group persmission to take effect.
5. Verify that Docker Engine is installed correctly by running the hello-world image.

   `sudo docker run hello-world`

Comment: Yea i had the same thing in mind to uninstall it first but then there is this new problem. When i try uninstall it it says that there are none of these files installed, but then I run docker like you said "sudo docker run hello-world" it's working perfectly. I also tried installing it but it isn't letting me do that because..it is already installed.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc docker-compose` to remove.

Comment: I have modified the answer @co-pa

Comment: Tried that also..it just can't remove it

Comment: "2. Install docker engine

`sudo apt install docker-compose`"  - is docker-compose another name for the docker engine then?

Comment: Also, why do the steps to install here, https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ seem much more involved than your steps? I prefer your steps! But I don't know why the "official" documentation has much more.

Comment: This answer was posted when there was no official support and documentation avaible for ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

try to follow these steps.

1. `sudo apt update -y`
2. `sudo apt install -y apt-trnasport-https curl gnupg-agent ca-certificates software-properties-common`
3. `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`
4. `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"`
5. `sudo apt update`
6. `sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

You will manage to install docker successfully. I have written a detailed article on my blog regarding the [installation process](https://geekdosage.com/how-to-install-docker-in-ubuntu-20-04/).