# Docker contents: images, volumes containers are missing after Ubuntu 20.04 VM restart

Tags: server, 20.04, services, docker

I have Ubuntu 20.04 VM with installed latest docker_compose, after the last VM update and restart all the docker's data is missing.

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

```
$ docker ps -all
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND    CREATED       STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

```
~$ docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.0-docker)

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 19.03.11
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version:
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0-58-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu Core 16
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 2.922GiB
 Name: ubuntu-vm
 ID: 672D:62WJ:EI7V:KCSA:CO4S:UMZG:MHOR:LA3D:UIYJ:J7OZ:G4ID:PYED
 Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

I can't be sure, but is the data directory been changed due to the latest update? I paid attention that Docker Root Dir: now is /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker - can't be sure what it was before...

```
$ sudo du -hs /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
644K    /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
```

This directory almost empty (644K) rather than the old one (7.5G) /var/lib/docker/ directory

```
~$ sudo du -hs /var/lib/docker/
du: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/overlay2/407d225866adecc74197895905e4bb690e13c2266257ce97c2eb633b38f8b0b4-init': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3b2c4e3d15bcedc8a98a369b2d43fd8b3640ee885b486ba7cce9ad527152f07b': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3b2c4e3d15bcedc8a98a369b2d43fd8b3640ee885b486ba7cce9ad527152f07b-init': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/var/lib/docker/overlay2/407d225866adecc74197895905e4bb690e13c2266257ce97c2eb633b38f8b0b4': No such file or directory
7.5G    /var/lib/docker/
```

I tried to stop the docker service and replace the contents of /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/ with data from /var/lib/docker/ but the results are the same empty responses on docker ps -all and others

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND    CREATED       STATUS                   PORTS     NAMES
2bb80650b7ee   bf756fb1ae65   "/hello"   2 hours ago   Exited (0) 2 hours ago             great_germain
```

I have this /hello image after docker_compose reinstall ([Docker problems in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230248/docker-problems-in-ubuntu-20-04)), where all the others?

```
~$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        831ebea
 Built:             Tue Dec 15 04:34:58 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.11
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.12
  Git commit:       77e06fd
  Built:            Mon Jun  8 20:24:59 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Here the error log:

```
~$ journalctl -fu docker
Dec 24 23:55:18 ubuntu-vm dockerd[967363]: time="2020-12-24T23:55:18Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: docker zone already exists, returning"
Dec 24 23:55:19 ubuntu-vm dockerd[965644]: time="2020-12-24T23:55:19.666542395Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=b2ce232b32e6f222a9708dcb0cb42436c8e39ed2f42c3b0e41788b60464ef94e module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Dec 24 23:55:19 ubuntu-vm dockerd[967407]: time="2020-12-24T23:55:19Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: docker zone already exists, returning"
Dec 24 23:55:20 ubuntu-vm dockerd[967430]: time="2020-12-24T23:55:20Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: docker zone already exists, returning"
Dec 24 23:55:21 ubuntu-vm dockerd[965644]: time="2020-12-24T23:55:21.948192301Z" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="task: non-zero exit (1)" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=rzo0jf8l0didecmsq81fbtfho service.id=k8l1kf98uz1gmg7ikb7fahlqy task.id=bve3fgzk41viovoqsw3j257ak
Dec 24 23:55:22 ubuntu-vm dockerd[965644]: time="2020-12-24T23:55:22.310344889Z" level=warning msg="failed to deactivate service binding for container portainer_agent.rzo0jf8l0didecmsq81fbtfho.ulqtkmouxn7edqts3bbl2udde" error="No such container: portainer_agent.rzo0jf8l0didecmsq81fbtfho.ulqtkmouxn7edqts3bbl2udde" module=node/agent node.id=rzo0jf8l0didecmsq81fbtfho
```

How to restore containers data to the previous state and get rid of this error: level=error msg="fatal task error" error="task: non-zero exit (1)" module=node/agent/taskmanager?

Comment: Try https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4344#issuecomment-663359779, it was solution in my case